# Why can't I open the "root" folder in Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, filesystem, root

After I finished installing Xubuntu I tried opening the Folder "Root" which has a cross next to it (I didn't know what was that) I already know that Root is my hard drive so i opened it and I got this:

[image: Failed to open directory "root". Permission denied.]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I know that you already have your answer, but for completeness' sake you might want to take a look at this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_directory_structure) which describes the linux filesystem hierarchy standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/root` folder is the home folder of the root user (the administrator). That is, you (as a normal user) cannot see the personal stuff of the administrator which is fine and is the right thing to happen. Now, the *root partition* is just `/`. I guess you just misinterpreted the meaning of the folder `/root` and the root partition `/`.

The root partition (and corresponding folder) is called `/`. So if you need to see your file system you just need to type `/` in the locations bar.

Also, notice there is an item (in the image you uploaded) which reads `File System` under **DEVICES**. Click it and see what reads on the locations bar.

Comment: So how should i open the "Hard Disk" or is this already the hard disk??

EDIT: ok i got it thanks

Comment: Just type `/` in the locations bar.

Answer (score -1):

the "root" folder is located in `/` not `/root/` that is the root user or "superuser" s home folder, as such you need root access to open it